# JAVA 2D Scroll Game Layout and Obstacles with collision detection

Tags: java, android, eclipse, collision-detection

I've got a great idea for an android app. My big problem:
I'm a "beginner" in JAVA. I had Java at the IT university but that were absolute basics!
Normally i'm developing in .Net .

I make a vertical scrolling 2D game:
Splashscreen (no prob)
Main menu (no prob)
level overview (no prob)
Game itself (big prob :) )

Vertical scrolling: I can do it, enough tutorials
Game map and obstacles (no way)

How can I create a map (there are walls right and left)
the middle part is free for playing with obstacles.

There is (for example) a ball where fall down and you have to turn it in the right way before the ball disappear when the top border comes.

How can i detect a collision from the black wall and the red obstacles?
(thats an example, textures not included)

And not to forget, it moves down. I thought with AndEngine with camera...

Image:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzafsb041po9jc7/Unbenannt-2.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create a map

On the screen or in the memory?

- Jogl, lwjgl, .. there are too many things that you can start an opengl drawing on screen.(maybe AndEngine is better I dont know), you need to use version-compliant functions of opengl.
- If you need to generate wall information in memory, you can use a simple function superpositioned with a height-map. You need to compute surface normals to be able to put things on top of others.(Im not sure if android device is capable of realtime performance for high resolution)

For example, starting with a sine wave,

[image]

Adding a square wave on top of that,

[image]

Superpositioned case:

[image]

Adding random-height-map, you get one side of wall with randomness and you can generate it using only one or two lines of code(then you can save coordinates if you need to save CPU cycles more than memory space):

[image]

> How can i detect a collision

Do you need event-based or a direct detection?

- Priori detection: you shoot imaginary rays from ball with direction of ball's velocity vector. Test both walls' and red obstacles' coordinates for the ray intersection. If it intersects, it will know which object the ball will collide after n time-steps. (if everything goes unchanged) You can try multiple ray test that works background such as first test shoots rays from current position, next test shoots from next position of ball, next is next, ...
  Good: you will know before it collides, so you can stop it "just in time". You can compute where the ball will be jumped after collision too! Even for consecutive collisions.  Bad: needs more cpu cycles, recursion can kill performance. More than one moving objects will increase complexity exponentially.

Using "Counting Sort" algorithm on a separate object coordinate buffer before shooting rays, can make the tracing faster.

- Posteriori detection is simple since you check for only if ball's coordinate fits in an tolerance interval of any other object's coordinate.
  Good: this is the simplest. Bad: it already collided. May bug or explode, you will need to put the ball back to a reasonable position. If the physics behind is good, you wont need repositioning.
  The repulsion force can be derived from a truncated exponential potential or some simple step function.

Both types need an acceleration structure if number of objects are high. (KD-tree helps)

- You can hard-code the collision zones. Every new object will add another line of code for the implementation. Needs the least cpu cycles. (example,a collision map to check if a position is a wall-position or any other obstacle, 1 for collision  and 0 for non-collision, a map of 50x400 of 1s and 0s should not fill too much memory)

Comment: I would like to create maps in an editor, for example Adobe Photoshop. I want to draw the game limits (wall right and left) and if it is possible the obstacles. I have read / found a possible solution, detect by pixel color. All obstacle lines are black (wall and barriers). I have so been thinking that because every level have an other layout, colors and textures (for the variety).

Comment: This is what I was trying to say in the last part :) if every level has same color of walls, obstacles, etc,.. then its okay with that.  I used this once for my qbasic flight simulator and my plane was bouncing by "time/date indicator" because it was same color of some other planes :) If you need to use other colors, you can use a "collision map" which can save you all colors. 1 for colision square, 0 for non collision.  As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

some more information:

I. use Andengine

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples

android app about examples: find "Andengine Examples" in Google Play

II. collision detection

Key part: collidesWith method
ex.:

```
if(line.collidesWith(face)) {

     line.setColor(1, 0, 0);

  } else {

     line.setColor(0, 1, 0);

  }
```

III. 
LevelLoader (works with xml) is a part of Andengine. You can use it.

ps: I had to create an own map editor to my game (in Google Play: "Pirates: Captain Jack"), where I save values to xml files.

Implementing an editor is a little bit time-consuming, but it worth.